# Display pages on index?action=

Tags: php

I would like to open a page using `index.php?do=settings`,
I'm using following code:

```
 $do='';
 if (isset($_GET['do'])){
    $do = strip_tags($_GET['action']);
 }

 if ($do == 'settings') {
    header("location:settings.php");
 }

if ($do == 'posts') {
        header("location:posts.php");
     }
```

but the problem is that I have manually add all menu in actions like above to make it work and when it redirects me, the `index.php?do=settings` disappears and just show me `settings.php` which I do not want

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not clear. You want to see **index.php?do=settings** in the url or **settings.php?do=setting**

Comment: @MuhammedHedayet He wants to redirect to `settings.php` but still have the same url `index.php?do=settings`

Comment: you redirect to settings.php so you loose the do get variable

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to set it manually you can store the pages in an array with the keys as the page name and the value as the file and then include the file:

```
$pages = array(
    'settings' => 'settings.php',
    'otherpage' => 'somePage.php'
);

if (isset($pages[$do])) {
    include $pages[$do];
}
```

You should include the file as the reason the URL changes is because of the redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this still won't show `index.php?do=settings`? Isn't there another way to do this? So that I do not need to store arrays? Something like the script gets the information by itself ?

Answer (score 0):

add the get var back in like so

```
header("location: http://yoursite.com/settings.php?do=".$do);
```

**NB:** that should be the full uri not a relative one

Answer (score 0):

You can use `http_build_query($_GET)` to generate the query string for links that need to conserve GET data.

If you need to modify a GET key, save GET to a temp array, modify that and pass it to `http_build_query`.